# Looking for a way to say that no buses or trams are arriving

Tags: sentence, translation

I am creating an app for Android in my locale language (French) and in English. It will display when the next buses or trams will be coming in real time. I would like to know if this sentence is correct :

"There are currently no arrival for the Baggersee (it's a stop name) stop starting at 3:00 AM."

I want to say that there is no bus starting at the time asked by the user.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks

Comment: It is inadequate as a sentence as I am not clear what it means. Is the person at the Baggersee stop, or elsewhere? If elsewhere I think it should be 'departures' rather than 'arrivals'. (In any event it should be plural.) Furthermore does it mean there will be no more buses to Baggersee after 3.00am, or that there isn't one at exactly 3.00am?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment before but curiousdannii answered to my question. I wanted to say that there is no bus at exactly 3.00 AM.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would say "There are no buses scheduled for Baggersee at 3:00 AM"

And of course, then put in when the next scheduled bus is!